# How to open fragment on a button click from an activity either with intent and without intent in android?

Tags: android

I tried the following code:

```
Intent in= new Intent(Activity1.this,Fragment.class);
startactivity(in);
```

Comment: The method does not say `startFragment`. Look into `FragmentManager`

Comment: You don't use intents at all.

Answer (score 6):

This is not [how fragments work](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), fragments *must* be attached to an `Activity`. To get your desired effect you must either start a new `Activity` that contains the fragment you wish to show, or display the new fragment in the current `Activity`.

In order to decide between which approach to take, I would consider how you want the `Fragment` to affect the navigation of your interface. If you want the user to be able to get back to the previous view by using the *Back* button, you should start a new `Activity`. Otherwise you should replace a view in your current `Activity` with the new `Fragment`.

Though, it *is* possible to add a `Fragment` to the back stack, I would only attempt to do so if you are confident with the structure of your user interface.

To show a new fragment in the current `Activity` you can use a `FragmentTransaction`:

```
Fragment fragment = CustomFragment.newInstance();

FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

transaction.replace(R.id.container_layout, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: i just want to open that fragment when i click button in activity ?

Comment: @SunilKumar Yes, if I understand you correctly. The button can open the fragment directly in the current activity.

Answer (score 3):

write this code in your onCreate or in your intent:

```
 FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
 YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
 fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_contenier,fragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Fragments  not Open through Intent.

You should use Fragment manager.

```
Fragment fragment= new YourFragment(); 
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment); // fragment container id in first parameter is the  container(Main layout id) of Activity
transaction.addToBackStack(null);  // this will manage backstack
transaction.commit();
```

Sample Example of Fragment

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);

    Button button1= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1_Id);
    Button button2= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2_Id);


    return view;
}

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   Fragment fragment= new YourFragment(); 
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment); // fragmen container id in first parameter is the  container(Main layout id) of Activity
transaction.addToBackStack(null);  // this will manage backstack
transaction.commit();
}
});

}
```