# how to make a layout which change?

Tags: android

[image]

want this kind of layout which change according to the button pressed(multiple display in one activity).
dont want a navigation bar which is for all activities.

if you are not understanding what i am saying:
what i am doing: making a set of questions(mcq type) user give ans to each question and submit it(submit button is on the last question)

Comment: you can use tablayout with viewpager

Comment: You can use fragment  and load it dynamically on button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example creating a tab layout to show different screen for each tab.

[Link 1](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-tablayout-example-using-viewpager-fragments/)

[Link2](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/)

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38767891/2782894) will help you. Use fragment to change layout dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fragments for this kind of Functionality.Check this link..it would be helpful for your Requirement.
[How to replace a Fragment on button click of that fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228721/how-to-replace-a-fragment-on-button-click-of-that-fragment)?